# Targeting section classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, sections

I'm using a one page scrolling plugin (http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) to be more precise.

I've noticed that many one page scrolling tutorials & plugins use sections. I'm having some issues targeting the sections. What I'm trying to do is add simple navigation to the plugin so that users know what page they are on.

I thought the code would be rather simple just using

```
if ($(".page1").hasClass("active")) {
        console.log("page one active");
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is there something I'm missing regarding targeting sections with jQuery? All I need to figure out is how to correctly target the section then I can add classes to my navigation tab.

**EDIT**

```
<div class="main">  
  <section class="page1" id="pageone">
    <div class="content col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>FIRST<br>PAGE<br></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

    <section class="page2">
      <div class="content col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>SECOND <br> PAGE <br> YO!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code so we can help identify the issue? For example, are you adding/removing active classes on your <section> elements when the user interacts with your navigation? Can you post your HTML structure and any other JS that is relevant...happy to help

Comment: The javascript from the plugin adds the class to section, check out the link i provided & inspect element if you need to see it in working form =)

Comment: This plugin has a callback that you can define `afterMove: function(index) {}`, check on [git](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

Comment: Thanks skobaljic, I'm toying with it now, but I can't target the elements as specifically as this just triggers when the page moves. I'm wanting to add a "current" class to "Week One" (as an example) then when the user is one "Week Two" the class is applied to the relevant nav

Comment: You might want to take a look at [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), it is quite similar to the plugin you are using, but it offers many other options. One of them provides a very easy way to link a menu to it by using the `anchors` and the `menu` options.